# Jaxb should Marshalling internal Classes?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jaxb, marshalling

Look I have this piece of XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="ResourcesType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Classrooms">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="ResourceType" name="Resource" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Teachers">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="ResourceType" name="Resource" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Classes">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="ResourceType" name="Resource" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Special">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="0"/>
            <xs:enumeration value=""/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

I generated the classes from the schema using the eclipse plugin and I got this:

`ResourcesType` class with `Classes`, `ClassRooms` and `Teachers` inner classes.
In all this inner classes I have protected `List<Serializable>` content field.
It generated also `ClassesType`, `ClassRoomsType` and `TeachersType` as normal classes.

Why was generated this inner classes ? How would I set this List if the other classes are not serializable ?

Thank you
Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why was generated this inner classes ?

A JAXB implementation will inner classes for anonymous complex types.  This is done in order to reduce the possibilities of name conflicts of generated classes.

```
<xs:complexType name="ResourcesType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Classrooms">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="ResourceType" name="Resource" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      ...
    </xs:sequence>

    </xs:complexType>
```

---

> How would I set this List if the other
>   classes are not serializable ?

The allowed contents of the `content` property are `JAXBElement<ResourceType>` and `String`.  `Serializable` is a common interface to both these types that is a little more restrictive than `Object`.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
public static class Classes {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "Resource", type = JAXBElement.class)
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> content;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the content property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the content property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getContent().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ResourceType }{@code >}
     * {@link String }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<Serializable> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

The following example may help:

```
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import example.ResourcesType.Classrooms;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // This is the ObjectFactory that was generated by XJC
        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();

        // You can instantiate objects using the constructors
        ResourcesType resourcesType = new ResourcesType();

        // You can instantiate objects using the ObjectFactory
        Classrooms classRooms = objectFactory.createResourcesTypeClassrooms();
        resourcesType.setClassrooms(classRooms);

        // You can use the ObjectFactory to wrap an object in a JAXBElement
        ResourceType resourceType1 = new ResourceType();
        JAXBElement<ResourceType> jaxbElement1 = objectFactory.createResourcesTypeClassesResource(resourceType1);
        classRooms.getContent().add(jaxbElement1);

        ResourceType resourceType2 = objectFactory.createResourceType();
        JAXBElement<ResourceType> jaxbElement2 = objectFactory.createResourcesTypeClassesResource(resourceType2);
        classRooms.getContent().add(jaxbElement2);

        // You can create a JAXBContext on the package name of your generated classes
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("example");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        // You can also create an instance of JAXBElement without using the ObjectFactory
        JAXBElement<ResourcesType> rootElement = new JAXBElement<ResourcesType>(new QName("root"), ResourcesType.class, resourcesType);
        marshaller.marshal(rootElement, System.out);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes but how would I add the objects to this List ? Should I implement serializable at my Types or change the List to my ResourceType ?

Comment: @user819285 - You need to wrap instances of `ResourceType` in an instance of `JAXBElement` before adding them to the List.

Comment: how ? example please ? I'm newbie sorry.

Comment: If you have any good reference website about this point.. please send me the link.

Comment: @user819285 - I have updated my answer with an example that should help.  I lead EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) and maintain a JAXB blog (http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/) that you may find helpful.